# vim avoid selecting underscore

Tags: vim, vi

So I know that an underscore (`_`) is considered part of a word in `vim`. Working with Python, I normally end up having a lot of underscores. Is there a way to select part of a word excluding the underscore? For example in `long_name`, I'd just love to quickly select `long`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want, you can use

```
:set iskeyword-=_
```

...which will mean that underscores are no longer counted as parts of a word (this doesn't affect WORDs). You can reverse this with:

```
:set iskeyword+=_
```

These can easily be set to some keybinding:

```
:nnoremap <f2> :set iskeyword-=_
:nnoremap <s-f2> :set iskeyword+=_
```

Someone with a bit with a bit more vimscripting skill than I could probably work out a way to have a toggle button, rather than separate on and off keys.

Comment: Also, `:set iskeyword&` can reset it to its default according to vim doc.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [vim-textobj-underscore](https://github.com/lucapette/vim-textobj-underscore) plugin.

Excerpt from the README:

> The `textobj-underscore` plugin provides two new text-objects which are triggered by `a_` and `i_` respectively. You can use them when you have to deal with the following type of words:
>
> `foo_bar_baz`
>
> Now, suppose you have to change `bar` to `qux` (`*` for cursor position). You can do the following:
>
> `foo_b*ar_bar`
>
> and type `ci_` to get
>
> `foo_*_bar`
>
> Or you can type `da_` to get `foobar`

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [camelcasemotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905); it provides motions to jump to each fragment, and text objects to select / work on such part (both including and excluding the underscore).